# Why does the Worksheets.Protect not work in this VBA Worksheet_Deactivate() Event?

Tags: vba, excel

The code in the deactivate event works perfectly when I do press another worksheet. The only thing that does not work is the last 2 lines before the procedure ends (Protecting the worksheet). I have another deactivate event procedure that also protects the same 2 worksheets and it works. It only does not work in this specific one. I also tried Worksheets(2).Protect and Worksheets(4).Protect and they also do not work in the deactivate event.

When I debug using F8 which runs the code line by line, it will protect the sheet and work as it should. But it would not activate through the deactivate event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
Dim Total_rows_Fin As Long
Dim Total_rows_Dash As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim z As Long

Total_rows_Dash = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Total_rows_Fin = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Finished").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

j = 0
ReDim c(0 To Total_rows_Dash) As Long
For i = 2 To Total_rows_Dash
    If Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(i, 6) = "D" Then
        j = j + 1
        For z = 1 To 6
            Worksheets("Finished").Cells(Total_rows_Fin + j, z) = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(i, z)
            c(i) = 1
        Next z
    End If
Next i

For i = 2 To Total_rows_Dash
    For j = 2 To 6
        If c(i) = 1 Then Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(i, j).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Next j
Next i

Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Protect
Worksheets("Dashboard").Protect

End Sub
```

**Below are some extra information:**

The image of my VBE opened workbooks and macros:

[image]

The code of another event which is a worksheet_activate event prior to the deactivate event of the same worksheet:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim Total_rows_Pick As Long
Dim Total_rows_Dash As Long
Dim Total_rows_Prod As Long
Dim Total_rows_Fin As Long
Dim Total_rows_PC As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim m As Variant

Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Unprotect
Worksheets("Dashboard").Unprotect

'Clears Contents
Total_rows_Dash = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A2:A1048576").ClearContents
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B2:B1048576").ClearContents
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("C2:C1048576").ClearContents
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("D2:D1048576").ClearContents
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("E2:E1048576").ClearContents

'Counts total number of rows
c = 0
Total_rows_Pick = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Pick-ups").Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Total_rows_Prod = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Total_rows_Fin = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Finished").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Total_rows_Dash = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Total_rows_Pick
    m = 0
    c = 0
    For j = 1 To Total_rows_Dash
        If Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 2) And Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 4) = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 1) Then
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next j
        For y = 1 To Total_rows_Fin
            If c = 0 And Worksheets("Finished").Cells(y, 2) = Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 2) And Worksheets("Finished").Cells(y, 1) = Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 4) Then
                m = 1
            End If
        Next y
        If m = 0 Then
            Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(Total_rows_Dash + 1, 2) = Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 2)
            Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(Total_rows_Dash + 1, 1) = Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 4)
            Total_rows_Dash = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        End If
Next i

For i = 2 To Total_rows_Pick
    For j = 2 To Total_rows_Dash
        m = Application.Match(Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 4), Worksheets("Finished").Range("A2:A1048576"), 0)
        If IsError(m) Then
            If Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 2) = Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 2) And Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 4) = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 1) Then
                Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 3) = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 3) + Worksheets("Pick-ups").Cells(i, 3)
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

For k = 2 To Total_rows_Prod
    For j = 2 To Total_rows_Dash
        m = Application.Match(Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Cells(k, 5), Worksheets("Finished").Range("A2:A1048576"), 0)
        If IsError(m) Then
            If Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 2) = Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Cells(k, 3) And Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Cells(k, 5) = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 1) Then
                Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 4) = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(j, 4) + Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Cells(k, 18)
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next k

Total_rows_PC = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
If Total_rows_PC <> Total_rows_Dash And Total_rows_PC <= Total_rows_Dash Then
    If Total_rows_PC = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(2, 5) = "=(D2/C2)*100"
    End If
End If

Total_rows_PC = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
If Total_rows_PC <> Total_rows_Dash And Total_rows_PC <= Total_rows_Dash Then
    Range("E" & Total_rows_PC).AutoFill Destination:=Range("E" & Total_rows_PC, "E" & Total_rows_Dash), Type:=xlFillDefault
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheets` will implicitly refer to the active workbook. It is almost always better to explicitly reference the workbook and worksheet. Are you certain the activeworkbook is the workbook you expect, before calling `Workeheets`?

Comment: Yes i'm sure since all my worksheets are in one workbook. All the events are also within the same workbook's modules. I have two events under the same worksheet though. One is activate one is deactivate although i'm pretty sure it should not have an effect. I can post the whole event list in the main post if it wont make things too messy

Comment: You only have one workbook open?

Comment: Yes although there are some add-ins: FUNCRES.XLAM and SOLVER.XLAM are also open. I'll add the photo of my VBE

Comment: And which `workbook`/`add-in` is the code that this runs stored in? It doesn't look like it is in the `workbook` that you're trying to save

Comment: It is on the `Hourly Production` Workbook under the `Dashboard` Worksheet which is the one highlighted in the picture @Tom. I also tried  `Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Prod. Qty.").Protect` and `Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Dashboard").Protect` it still doesn't work

Comment: The `Protect` method has a lot of properties. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel. Your call relies on the defaults for all of them. I tried to research whether Excel actually remembers the properties last used on each sheet, or on any sheet, but didn't find anything. So, how would you know which kind of protection is applied? Is it the one last set for each sheet? Or the one last set for any sheet? And if there is no password, how would you know that protection was NOT applied?

Comment: There is a way to put a password with the `Protect` method but I chose not to. Also, for the kind of protection that is applied I am not sure how to set up which aspects of the worksheet is to be protected. However, based on my previous codes it always prevented the worksheet from being edited, at the minimum, which is sufficient for me. I can also tell it was not protected even with no password because under the `Review` tab of the Excel ribbon,  you can see if its protected or unprotected. Also I can still type in the worksheet

Comment: What are you expecting it to `Protect`? When you `Protect` the sheet manually through the Excel UI do you get the expected behaviour?

Comment: Yes I do if I manually do it. If I run the code using `F8 button` which runs the code 1 line at a time, it also works without a problem. But in this event it does not work. That is the problem. So I was wondering why the code works when I deactivate it except for the worksheet protection part

Comment: in which sheet you use Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() and in which you use Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()?I mean you use the above to the same sheet or on different sheets

Comment: Same sheet for both although I don't see why it should have a problem. The activate is prior to the deactivate. If you notice in the activate is the unprotect and in the deactivate is the protect. The deactivate comes latter

Comment: I even added a MsgBox "Hello" between, before, and after the `Protect`'s and it works. But the `Protect` simply does not get recognized